# How can I make data visible on an alert box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is fully functional. I want to check all the data. Using this, I can't see all the data.

```
alert("SHOW FORM DATA");   
alert(PreparedFormObj());
```

**FORM DATA**

```
var PreparedFormObj = function () {
    var _FormData = new FormData()
    _FormData.append('Id', $("#Id").val())
    _FormData.append('CreatedDate', $("#CreatedDate").val())
    _FormData.append('CreatedBy', $("#CreatedBy").val())
    _FormData.append('ProductId', $("#ProductId").val())
    _FormData.append('ProductModelNo', $("#ProductModelNo").val())
    _FormData.append('Name', $("#Name").val())

    return _FormData;
}
```

**SAVE DATA**

```
var SaveProduct = function () {   

    alert("SHOW FORM DATA");
    alert(PreparedFormObj());

}
```

Comment: `alert()` requires a string; you are passing it a `FormData()` object. Perhaps try returning `_FormData.stringify()`?

Comment: Don't use `alert()`.  Use `console.log(...)` and view in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example convert to json

```
alert(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(PreparedFormObj())));
```